# "The daily life of my cats" ? or "My cats' daily life"?

Tags: phrase-choice

I'm making a webcomic about my cats, I'm ready to publish it, but I have a huge doubt regarding the title. Because, according to Google Translate (yes, I know, it's not the best reference...) both of the sentences can be used... But I'm not sure. So what is the best, please?

I'm a French native, by the way

Comment: The first sentence is probably the best one.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of correctness and ease of understanding I see no significant difference.

Instinctively I prefer

> The daily life of my cats

but I find it difficult to explain why. Some possible reasons, which may be very much a matter of taste:

1. We dodge the use of the possessive apostrophe. Yes the usage is correct, but somehow its very correctness is a little dull!
2. The "cats' life" possessive could have an implication of true ownership, as though you you are writing this from the perspective of the cats, with self-awareness.
3. I find the rhythm of the first sentence better, it finishes on a strong consonant. I occasionally write songs and this sense emphasis can make big difference.

Comment: I don't know that we dodge the use of the possessive apostrophe but the *plural possessive apostrophe* is one that takes a bit of effort on the reader's part to correctly understand.  *My cats' daily life* is first heard/read as *my cat's daily life* and then I must read back to see that you mean your cats and not your cat.  This is fine in a sentence but not so useful as a title.

Comment: I think both should work.  It is not as difficult as changing 'man of the match' to match's man ;)

Comment: lovely example, I'll never watch day's match in the same way again.

Answer (score 1):

They are grammatically equivalent.

Which works better as a title is a matter of personal opinion, but I’d prefer *My Cats’ Daily Life* purely because it’s shorter. In prose, the choice would depend on whether I wanted to emphasize the cats or their life.